# Not understand on behavior

Tags: react-native

Currently, I am learning react native and still don't know why it happened.
I have a component A and component B.

In component A when handle success I will pass isSucceeded: true and false for the failure case.
 but I don't know why  when having success case it navigates to B screen and always show `Fail` text before showing `Success` text for 1 second

```
component A: 

login() {
   dataService.getService().then((response) => {
       navigateService.navigate('B', {isSucceeded: true})
    }).catch(error => {
     navigateService.navigate('B', {isSucceeded: false})
    });
}
```

In component B:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.state.isSucceeded = navigation.getParam('isSucceeded')
}

render() {
 this.state.isSucceeded ? <View> <Text>Success</Text></View> : 
                          <View> <Text>Fail</Text></View>
}
```

How can it show Success Text when having success case and fail for failed case

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in the `constructor`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isSucceeded: props.navigation.getParam('isSucceeded'),
  };
}
```

If you insist doing it in `componentDidMount` then you must use `setState()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const isSucceeded = this.props.navigation.getParam('isSucceeded');

  this.setState({ isSucceeded });
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference from setState and state = params? ( sorry if it's a stupid question)